# Error when bulk updating Saleforce

Tags: bulk-api

I have a dataframe of two columns namely Id and datetimehelp (Holds time stamp value).

Given below is the view of the data in the dataframe labelled account_update_subset

```
Id,datetimehelp
123,18/05/18 9:50
567,18/05/18 9:45
```

I am writing the below Python code to have this update to a Salesforce object (Account) but it throws me an error **Response content: {'exceptionCode': 'InvalidBatch', 'exceptionMessage': 'Records not processed'}**

```
if len(account_update_subset) > 0:
    key_update_attributes_list = []
    update_attributes_list = []
    for i in range(len(account_update_subset)):
        update_attributes_data = {'Id': account_update_subset['Id'].iloc[i],
                              'datetimehelp': account_update_subset['datetimehelp'].iloc[i]}

        update_attributes_list.append(update_attributes_data)
        sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.update(update_attributes_list)
```

Could anyone help me find where am I going wrong in this Python script. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure if it's the specific cause of this error, but your bulk Update call appears to be indented one stop too far. It belongs outside the loop.

Comment: @DavidReed, this works just fine if I try to pass a date timestamp in the format dd/mm/yy. This error pops out if the format is dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss if this might help..

Comment: Is the Salesforce field a Date or DateTime field? `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss` is likely not valid. This looks like `simple_salesforce`; is that right?

Comment: Try using `yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ` format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming here that you're using [`simple_salesforce`](https://github.com/simple-salesforce/simple-salesforce), because your bulk invocation looks like that API.

It's not immediately clear to me which of these issues causes the specific error you're observing, but I see at least three issues with this code.

1. You are repeatedly updating the same Accounts, which results in creation of way more of your limited Bulk API jobs than you probably want to use.

   ```
   for i in range(len(account_update_subset)):
       update_attributes_data = {'Id': account_update_subset['Id'].iloc[i],
                         'datetimehelp': account_update_subset['datetimehelp'].iloc[i]}

       update_attributes_list.append(update_attributes_data)
       sf_data_cursor.bulk.Account.update(update_attributes_list)
   ```

Note that here, your `update()` call is *inside* the `for` loop where you accumulate updatable Accounts in `update_attributes_list`. You should move that `update()` call *outside* the loop, so that you call it exactly once for the entire list in a single operation. Right now, the first Account in your list is getting updated `len(account_update_subset)` times.

2. You appear to be providing an invalid field for update, `'datetimehelp'`. If this is a custom field, you'll need to refer to it by the proper API name, such as`'datetimehelp__c'`.
3. The date-time values you're providing in `dd/mm/yy hh:mm:ss` are not a valid format for Salesforce to accept. The valid incoming formats are documented [here](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=Data-Loader-Import-data-for-Date-or-Date-Time-field-1327108684799&language=en_US&type=1) and depend on whether your target field is Date or DateTime in type:

> YYYY-MM-DD
>   YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
>   YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss
>   YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ssZ
>   YYYY-MM-DDThh:mm:ss.sssZ

Comment: thanks for your reply. My apologies for keying in few in-correct data. Point 2 and 3 are as per what you mentioned. However I see the error  is when the bulk.Account.update happens. And I am trying to figure how to modify the for loop to satisfy that. On another note, if I try to update just the date component (YYYY-MM-DD) to a column of type Date it works just fine. However when I try to update a  value (YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss) to a column of type Date/time this error throws up..

Comment: @darkhorse You need to un-indent the update call by one tab to remove it from the loop.